# how to save multiple video of large size in document directory using NsData without Memory Issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, nsdata, document

i write this code but App crash due to High memory consumptions.

```
 -(void)saveToDir
  {
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:[assets objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] options:[PHVideoRequestOptions new] resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                  {
                      if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]])
                      {
                          NSURL *url = [(AVURLAsset*)asset URL];
                          urlFromLibrary=url;
                          AVAsset *asset=[selectedImageArray objectAtIndex:i];
                          NSURL *url = [(AVURLAsset*)asset URL];
                          NSString *filename = [[url path] lastPathComponent];
                          NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

                          NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:url,filePath, nil];

                          NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
                          if (data)
                          {
                              if([data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES])
                              {
                                  NSLog(@“write successfull”);

                              }
                              else{
                                  NSLog(@“write failed”);
                              }
                          }

                          //  [self downloadVideoAndSave:url :filePath];

                      }
}];
```

i wrote this above code but app crash with memory issue so better response

Comment: please try setting NSData *data and AVAsset *asset=  to nil once writing is successful or failed

Comment: You don't need to read the file content to memory. Just use -[NSFileManager copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:].

Comment: @adymerets this one work , thanks but its taken more time when large video so please suggest